# Qt: difference between VERSION and VER_MAJ, VER_MIN, VER_PAT in qmake

Tags: c++, qt, version, qmake

I'm using linux for a shared library in Qt5.

since using in `.pro` any of:

```
VERSION = 1.2.3
```

or

```
VER_MAJ = 1
VER_MIN = 2
VER_PAT = 3
```

generate the same output name for the library (lib.so, lib.so.1, lib.so.1.2, lib.so.1.2.3), what's the actual difference?

Qt documentation states:

> **VERSION** Specifies the version number of the application if the app
>   template is specified or the version number of the library if the lib
>   template is specified.
>
> **VER_MAJ** Specifies the major version number of the library if the lib
>   template is specified.
>
> **VER_MIN** Specifies the minor version number of the library if the lib
>   template is specified.
>
> **VER_PAT** Specifies the patch version number of the library if the lib
>   template is specified.

Since I'm not using `app` template, are both the same? There are reason why I should prefer one of these?

Edit: It seems `VER_MAJ, VER_MIN, VER_PAT` have always priority over `VERSION` in the definition of che library version output, regardless the order of definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Qt documentation states

Concerning `qmake`, Qt documentation is not really accurate, to say the least. One should always consult the `qmake`'s source code to find out the truth.

So after some digging into the source it looks like:

1. **Win**: `VERSION` is used for Windows resources (both application and library); `VER_MAJ` is used for a shared library suffix (e.g. "mylib1.dll") only; if `VER_MAJ` is not set, then it's initialized from `VERSION`; `VER_MIN` and `VER_PAT` are ignored.
2. ***nix**: `VERSION` is ignored, except if some of `VER_MAJ`, `VER_MIN` or `VER_PAT` are not set directly, then they are initialized indirectly from `VERSION`.

So, for Win, one should probably use `VERSION` only. For *nix, there's no real difference.

Comment: Try I did show the exact opposite you said: when both `VERSION` and `VER_MAJ, VER_MIN, VER_PAT` are defined, the latters have priority over `VERSION` when generating the `.so` version number. The order of declaration does not count. At least is what happens to my Linux distro.